# Use of join method in CompletableFuture class vs get method

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I wanted to implement a functionality where a big file gets broken down into chunks and processing can happen in parallel.

I used CompletableFuture to run tasks in parallel. 
unfortunately , it doesnt work unless i use join. Im surprised that this is happening, since according to docs, get is also a blocking methd in the class which returns the result. can someone please help me in figuring out what  i am doing wrong.

```
//cf.join(); if i uncommnet this everything works
```

in case i uncomment the above line in the method processChunk, everything works fine. my values are printed and everything. however if i remove it, nothing happens. all i get are notifications that futures have copleted but the contents are not printed .

This is my output

```
i cmpleteddone
i cmpleteddone
i cmpleteddone
i cmpleteddone
i cmpleteddone
```

My text file is a pretty small file(for now)

```
1212451,London,25000,Blocked 
1212452,London,215000,Open 
1212453,London,125000,CreditBlocked 
1212454,London,251000,DebitBlocked 
1212455,London,2500,Open 
1212456,London,4000,Closed 
1212457,London,25100,Dormant 
1212458,London,25010,Open 
1212459,London,27000,Open 
12124510,London,225000,Open 
12124511,London,325000,Open 
12124512,London,425000,Open 
12124513,London,265000,Open 
12124514,London,2577000,Open 
12124515,London,2504400,Open


package com.org.java_trial.thread.executors;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;




public class ProcessReallyBigFile {

    private static final ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    private static CompletableFuture<String> processChunk(List<String> lines) {

        CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

            //just for purposes of testing, will be replaced with major function later
            lines.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
            return "done";
        }, ex);

        //cf.join(); if i uncommnet this everything works
        return cf;
    }

    private static void readInChunks(String filepath, Integer chunksize) {

        List<CompletableFuture<String>> completable = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filepath))) {

            String line = null;
            List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
            int count = 0;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (count % chunksize == chunksize - 1) {

                    collection.add(line);
                    completable.add(processChunk(collection));

                    collection.clear();

                } else {

                    collection.add(line);
                }
                count++;
            }

            // any leftovers
            if (collection.size() > 0)
                completable.add(processChunk(collection));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for (CompletableFuture c : completable) {
            c.join();
            if (c.isDone() || c.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
                try {

                    System.out.println("i cmpleted" + c.get());
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        ex.shutdown();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filepath = "C:\\somak\\eclipse-workspace\\java_thingies\\java_trial\\account_1.csv";

        readInChunks(filepath, 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is this:

```
collection.clear();
```

your control returns back to the calling method without `.join()` and the collection that your task is referring to get's cleared. `luck you ain't getting an exception thrown for concurrent access`. concurrent access to shared resources should always be synchronized. I would have rather done this:

```
synchronized(collection) { 
   collection.clear(); 
}
```

and

```
synchronized(collection) {
   lines.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

this will ensure thread safety while accessing `collection` object as the thread will require to hold the monitor on instance `collection` before performing any update on it.

also, as pointed out by @Holger, do this:

```
synchronized(collection) {
   collection.add(line);
}
```

Comment: perfect. you are a god send. collection clear was the bad guy. and i truly appreciate the additonal info regarding synchronization. i will implement that as well

Comment: @user1906450 happy to help!

Comment: @user1906450 did it work for you? can you accept my answer if it did so others can benefit too?

Comment: It’s synchronize**d** with a d at the end. Further, it will only provide mutual exclusion, it does not guaranty that the `forEach` operation will run *before* the `clear`. Since the `forEach` could also run after the `clear`, you would have to protect the `add` operation with a `synchronized` too, not that it would fix the semantic error. It the end, the code could be easily fixed by creating a new `ArrayList` for every chunk, so no object is accessed concurrently and no `synchronized` needed.

Comment: @Holger that was my bad, made a typo with `synchronized`. with the `synchronized` my intent was to only prevent concurrent access. I agree that there is no guarantee of clear not executing 1st as the scheduler would decide that. though, I really feel creating a copy of ArrayList should be the last resort considering the amount of work that would go in. you are welcome to make edits to my answer with some workarounds !

Comment: There’s no additional amount of work, as we’re not talking about “creating a copy”, but replacing `collection.clear()` with `collection = new ArrayList<>()`, to *get an empty list*. Each asynchronous job is supposed to work on a different chunk, so using different list instances for each chunk is a natural approach. Reusing the same list instance does not have any advantage, but creates the need for all the synchronization.

Comment: @Holger I mistook what you said. that's indeed the right way! anyways, the culprit was .clear()!